# Good little project to do when learning C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, twitter-client

I want to write a little application for myself to learn C# and WPF.

The typical hello world in 2009 (twitter client) seems boring. I would like to hear your stands should I do a twitter client? Any other starters I could play around with and get used to c#? (I'm a longtime PHP programmer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Twitter client ends up being a good way to get started with WPF, for a few reasons:

- It's got lists of data with images, which gives you practice with formatting and styling lists
- There are a lot of options for styling what you're working on - partly due to the avatars, limited text blocks, etc.
- A Twitter app is the kind of application where you expect to see good UI
- There are some good libraries availble (I highly reccommed tweet#) so you don't need to bother with any of the plumbing
- It's something you can show off and be proud of - people will understand what it does
- There are plenty of complex things you can add on later if you want - skinning, drag and drop, autocomplete, spell checking, etc.
- There are some open source WPF clients out there, so you can find some sample code if you get stuck

And the number 1 reason why it's good idea... you can start contributing your code to the [Witty project](http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/). We'd love more help!

Comment: +1. Great answer. Totally beat me to it! Contribute to Witty.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to write a native GUI (WPF) client for your most recent PHP project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a modelling tool (business processes flow/UML (classes)/execution flow i.e. scripts execution flow/etc...).

Answer (score 0):

[WPF Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa740389.aspx) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Only do a twitter client if that's what you're interested in. I don't see why twitter should be the new "hello world.", except maybe for making such a thing, like a twitter or facebook bot.

If you want to focus on C# and OOP, try something with many objects interacting, like a simple fighting game, poker, black-jack, etc.

If you want to learn wpf, try some fancy interface stuff, like a calculator, a video player, a photo gallery.

You're only limited to your imagination. Try to pick something fun, or something you'd like your computer to do, and code away. :D