# Who can give me an idea for 'just for fun' project[wpf]?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm learning wpf and c#, and now i need an idea for wpf project. Help me please, ideas, or sites and else... Thanks!

Comment: You can do my projects!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183275/good-little-project-to-do-when-learning-c-wpf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308101/suggestions-for-wpf-wcf-projects

Answer (score 17):

Make a project around one of your hobbies or interests to make it a bit easier. For instance, if you're an avid reader, build a small library of your books or if you collect baseball cards, maybe an app to organize your cards.

Comment: +1, you beat me (with the same answer as me) by seconds! :)

Comment: good suggestion. thats how I like learning new stuff too

Answer (score 7):

Look at the [coding for fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/) website for all sort of fun ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Make a simple game, like tic tac toe for example. A little more advance you can try a simple labyrinth game or tetris game.

Simulation of real physical forces and relations is also amusing - gravitation or magnetism for example.

And another idea - make a music visualizer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like Space Invaders or Asteroids is fun to clone. Action games like that are slightly more difficult than Chess or something similar, and you have to learn a wider range of stuff to get them to work.

Comment: thanks, apparantly games it's the best way for study.

Answer (score 2):

Write a utility for one of your old projects. Configuration editor, XML editor, or something similar. Make sure to play with bindings. Games will only teach you a small subset of WPF, I'd suggest making some useful application so you learn all aspects.

Answer (score 1):

How about a program that scans a folder for images and displays them as thumbnails.
The window should be re-sizable, as should the thumbnail sizes.

Bonus points if you double click a thumbnail and it zooms in to full size.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to pick something that would help make my work easier as a developer.  So think of something that would make you more productive, plus add business value that someone else may benefit from...  Or choose something you like and create a WPF app for it...

Could be a game, or a business app for storing contacts, etc.  Or something else that might benefit you with your job...

Answer (score 1):

So if it's WPF then we're talking about desktop software, right?

I don't know if you game much or not, but I've seen a few smallish utilities related to various games.  For example, someone wrote a config-file editor for Borderlands: http://gbxforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=85874 (scroll down a bit for a screen shot).

Or maybe you have a development task that you could automate with a small utility.  For example, I wrote myself a little command-line app that can strip the source control bindings out of a VSS-controlled Visual Studio solution.

That was a fun little one-day project where I got to play with disk IO and regular expressions.

Surely you have a few itches of your own.  Scratch one :)

Comment: yeah, desktop software. For embedded system i use a C and hex code.
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

I've got tons and tons of programs I want to write, and not enough time to do them all.

There are lots of games: connect-four, battleship, mastermind. For me, the fun part is the AI. Simulators are fun to write and play with. streets, electric circuits, stellar physics.

Just write what you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this series when starting with WPF, creating a Sudoku game and solver.  I highly recommend it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/11/06/999502.aspx